# .net Core MVC: X-SRF-TOKEN not accepted, 400 returned

Tags: angularjs, cookies, asp.net-core, csrf

I have a .net core app using angularJS, and I want to protect the api calls protected by our cookie based authentication. I Followed the steps in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery

- I added the `services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");` to my services configuration
- I am seeing the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie in my developer tools when loading the page.
- I am seeing the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header being added to my $http sent requests.
- I have added the `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` to my controller that is handling the ajax request.
- I have ssl enabled, and am accessing the pages via https.

I can make GET requests fine through this api endpoint as expected. However, I am receiving a 400 error without any details of why the request was bad on PUTs and POSTs.

I know the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` is on the request,  (seen in the network tab of chrome dev tools) so I am unsure what I am missing to allow these requests to be received correctly.

**TL;DR:** Why is .net core rejecting my valid AntiforgeryToken?

**UPDATE** Attempted @joey's suggested solution, but it did not work, still receiving 400 responses. code below reflects another solution I tried to fix this problem (aka angularjs's solution to setting default cookies and headers for cross site scripting protection)

I have also attempted to configure AngularJS to change what the cookie and header names match what I configured in my `Startup.cs`. I changed their names to try both `XSRF-TOKEN` (cookie) and `X-XSRF-TOKEN` (header) as well as `CSRF-TOKEN` and `X-CSRF-TOKEN`, and while the configurations within angular is correctly using the new default to what ever I provide, my authentication code in .net core is still not working.

for more information here is how i am configuring AngularJS:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'CSRF-TOKEN';
});
```

here is the `ConfigureServices` line I have in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN");
```

and lastly here is the code I added to the `Configure` method of the `Startup.cs` file:

```
    app.Use(next => context => 
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
        if (path.Contains("/MyProtectedPath/"))
        {
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("CSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
        }
        return next(context);
    });
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I have added the following to my controller action:

```
if (HttpContext.Request.Method.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) != "get")
{
    await _antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext);
}
```

`AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.`

I thought maybe `antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context)` might be overriding the current cookie sent on the page load, so I make it only hit that code on GET requests, but I get the same result for the posts.

**Update 3**
Thanks @joey for your help, I have looked at my startup.cs file, and I have the UseAuthentication in a seperate branch:

```
    app.Use(next => context => //note: order of these use statements is key. keep this antiforgery section above auth!
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
        if (path.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains("/campaigns/proxy/"))
        {
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
        }
        return next(context);
    });

    // Use Basic Auth for /api
    app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")), branch =>
    {
        branch.UseBasicAuth();
    });
    // Use Identity for everything except /api
    app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")), branch =>
    {

        app.UseAuthentication(); // required for .net core 2.0 authentication
    });
```

I am not sure why my tokens would be considered invalid at this point...

Comment: I noticed in the article, it mentions the webapi controller rather than the MVC controller I am currently using. Would this make a difference?

Comment: so have you solved the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no. I ran out of time getting this to work.

Comment: man, it is driving me crazy, I followed the documentation to the last every single detail, I have been applying many other methods I encountered during my search, nothing helped. its becoming frustrating, I am opening an issue on Github

Comment: app.UseAuthentication(); isn't using branch

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have posted, you are adding the header `X-XSRF-TOKEN`, but the header should be `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.

The example from the web page you linked provides the example:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN");
```

**Update:**

Thanks for clarifying with the additional code & information. The means of implementing CSRF selected here is one which passes the token as a header on the response of the initial HTML file. Here is an example of how such a case might be configured for a SPA web application:

```
app.Use(next => context =>
{
    string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
    if (
        string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
        string.Equals(path, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    )
    {
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("CSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, 
            new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
    }

    return next(context);
});
```

However, with your service configured to using the String.Contains method [1], `antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context)` is invoked for any path containing `/MyProtectedPath/` anywhere. This means it has been configured in such a way that matches not only `/MyProtectedPath/`, but also `/MyProtectectedPath/a/b/c` or `/a/b/c/MyProtectedPath/`.

To check the CSRF token sent in subsequent requests of an applicable HTTP method as shown below:

```
if (string.Equals("POST", context.Request.Method, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    await antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);
    // The line above will throw if the CSRF token is invalid.
}
```

If the method `GetAndStoreTokens` is called before this for any matching path, the token will be overwritten before it is checked, which is why .net examples will typically order `GetAndStoreTokens` first, but with the specific condition for looking at the path and HTTP method.

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So in the article linked above from Microsoft states I can override the default header name with the angular default `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. Is this feature to override the default header name broken?

Comment: @NathanTregillus Thanks for updating with the additional configuration code, it's helpful! Are the HTTP requests returning the 400 status code nested under the path `/MyProtectedPath/`?

Comment: Correct. The method itself is not getting reached. If I take the attribute off, the call goes through correctly.

Comment: Hey @Joey, just want to clarify, I should use `antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);` on get requests, and `antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);` for the non-get requests correct?

Comment: The reason I ask, is because I thought this `antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);` method was suppose to be called by the `AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken` attribute... why would i need this attribute if the pipeline context setup is validating?

Comment: @NathanTregillus Yes, generally will not need to call `antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context)` for a GET request. `AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken` is one of the ASP.NET MVC filters, so it is intended for forms created using ASP.NET MVC (which will add something along the lines of `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="..." />` to each HTML from). Since you are using Angularjs, I assume the forms are not being created using ASP.NET MVC and are instead sourced from static assets (HTML with bundled javascript, css, etc.)

Comment: Ah! so no wonder my api call to the endpoint fails, the endpoint is looking for the form field, not the header. I'm going to write an attribute that i can put on the get html endpoint, and the ajax endpoints that handling the post/delete/etc. thank you for the help! (I will write this up, and if it works, I'll mark this completed)

Comment: Hey @joey, unfortunately this is now throwing an error regarding the cookie value not matching the header request....  see update 2 for more info

Comment: @NathanTregillus This is progress! We now know the antiforgery token is being received, but is not valid. If you are using ASP.NET core v2, try adding `app.UseAuthentication();` **before** the `.GetAndStoreTokens(context)` middleware in the `Configure` method. If you are on v1, use `app.UseIdentity();` instead of  `app.UseAuthentication();`. If I'm not mistaken, I believe CSRF implemented in ASP.NET relies on the user identity (even if it is anonymous or contains no authentication per se).

Comment: @NathanTregillus this answer is correct. Hope you managed to get it working!

Comment: I have not gotten to try this last move, but I will try now. I awarded you the reward for all your help! thank you so much!

Comment: So i took a look, and i have my authenticate below my get and store logic @jo

Comment: I am currently facing the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48038980/2157801), none of the mentioned above helped me to get it right

Answer (score 1):

This is the configuration that worked for me,
I have `CORS` enabled,

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins("https://www.artngcore.com:4200") //Note:  The URL must be specified without a trailing slash (/).
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

then the add the following to your services at startup,

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
                {
                    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
                    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
                });
```

and the middleware,

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
                app.Use(next => context =>
                   {
                       string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
                       var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                       context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                            new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false, 
Secure = true // set to false if not using SSL });
                       return next(context);
                   });
```

and in the controller,

```
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller ....
```

configure your header as following,

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': `${this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')}`
});
```

Finally, what does the trick is that the **token has to be refreshed** after login (authentication), what I did is just call an API path just to invoke the token to refresh, 
i.e., call this API after login,

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactInitialization()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);

        return StatusCode(200);

    }
```

Hope it will help,

Comment: Manually implementing the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header on the client fixed the issue for me. It seems that Angular's built-in XSRF mitigation does not function correctly when the Angular app is hosted on a separate site from the API app it calls.

Answer (score 0):

Joey's answer seems to be right. But since you've mentioned it doesn't work for you here's what I had to do to get it working.

First, [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#angularjs):

> AngularJS uses a convention to address `CSRF`. If the server sends a cookie with the name `XSRF-TOKEN`, the Angular `$http` service will add the value from this cookie to a header when it sends a request to this server. This process is automatic; you don't need to set the header explicitly. The header name is `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. The server should detect this header and validate its contents.

#### Add the AntiForgery service

Add the Antiforgery service to the service collection in `Startup.ConfigureServices()` after the call to `AddMvc()`:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
});
```

We're basically telling ASP.NET to look for the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header while validating the xsrf token.

### Send a cookie with the token

Now on every request from the SPA, we need to send a `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie with the token value. We can do that with a quick middleware:

```
// TODO: Refactor this to a separate middleware class
app.Use(next => context =>
{
    // TODO: Add if conditions to ensure the cookies
    // are only sent to our trusted domains

    // Send the token as a javascript readable token
    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    context.Response.Cookies.Append(
        "XSRF-TOKEN", 
        tokens.RequestToken, 
        new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false }
    );

    return next(context);
});
```

### Validate your actions

The easiest way to validate the tokens is to add the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute. A better option is to configure MVC to apply the `AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken` globally for all actions with the following in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));
```

[Read the docs on token validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#validateantiforgerytoken).